# Using Quickly to build a web browser

Tags: application-development, python, webkit

I've taken my first crack at building apps for Ubuntu. I created a simple web browser using [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg) made by Jono Bacon. I was wondering if there is a list that I can download that has all of the commands that webkit can use in a python environment?

Comment: Can you specify what kind of list you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the move from static PyGTK bindings to the dynamic GObject-introspection, you'll have to use the C-docs.

[Here](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/index.html) are the WebKit docs.

It might take some time to grasp how to translate these into Python, but it is the most complete documentation you'll find.

For example:

```
webkit_web_view_can_go_forward -> WebKit.WebView.can_go_forward
WEBKIT_LOAD_FINISHED -> WebKit.LoadStatus.FINISHED
```